# DDD, AutoMapper and Factories

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, automapper, factory

I've been studying DDD and seen a lot of code to be able to build a new api in my current job.

Let's assume the following layered architecture:

1. **Api**
2. **Application Services (ViewModel is here)**
3. **Domain (Domain Service and Domain Model are here)**
4. **Infra**

The **Application Service** uses **Automapper** to create a **Domain Model Object**, and passes it to **Domain Service Layer**. Is that correct?

If I already have a **Domain Model Object** ready to use there, why should I use a **Factory**? Would I be wrong ignoring factories at all?

Since I use **Automapper** to map **view model objects** to **domain model objects** , where does the **factory** appears? 
I have a feeling that i'm missing something big here.

Comment: I believe that this question is a good candidate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Ray, i'll ask it there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The Application Service uses Automapper to create a Domain Model Object, and passes it to Domain Service Layer. Is that correct?

No. That's how you write a CRUD system. The domain entity should protect it's own state and all modifications on the domain entity should be made through ***methods***.

Something like:

```
var user = repos.Get(userId);
user.ActivateAccount();
repos.Update(user);
```

Thus the application services should be modeled around actions and not to just pass along DTOs which look exactly like the domain entities.

> using your example, how would I pass a new user? Should I use AutoMapper to map to a DTO User, and in my Domain Layer call a factory

I would create am user  DTO which would contain a subset of the information in the domain entity user, just the information which is required to successfully create a user.

In the application service you can use a factory to create an entity and then fill it with the information from the DTO. I personally would create an entity without a factory, but provide mandatory information in the user constructor.

Comment: The method should be on a domain entity that acts as an aggregate root, of course.

Comment: Thanks @jgauffin , using your example, how would I pass a new user? Should I use AutoMapper to map to a DTO User, and in my Domain Layer call a factory?